# How to use EDB function to mounts database volume in folder project?

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, edb

I have a store.vol file and use EDB API to read it. I attack this file in my project but I can't find to read it. I look a example in: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/68144/Modifying-the-Call-History-on-Windows-Mobile
Code example:

```
CeMountDBVolEx(&m_ceguidDB, L"\\pim.vol", NULL, OPEN_EXISTING);
```

I want use `CeMountDBVolEx` to mounts my database volume in folder project.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is `m_ceguidDB`?

Comment: Pointer to a buffer that is filled with the CEGUID of the mounted database.

Comment: Is it throwing errors? I do not have a phone on my Mobile Devices, so I can not test it. What are the errors giving you? You tell [CeMountDbVolEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa517182.aspx) to `OPEN_EXISTING`. Does your "pim.vol" exist on your device?

Comment: I don't use pim.vol. I have a file store.vol. I attach it in my project and i want to open it. When I run code, it's not find store.vol. Bool rez = CeMountDBVolEx(&guid, L"\\store.vol", &cevo,OPEN_EXISTING); Result:rez==false.

Comment: The document I linked shows to call `GetLastError` when the result is false.

Comment: How did you create your store.vol? Is it verfified to work? You may use itsutils to check your store.vol file: pdblist can list and dump EDB files: http://itsme.home.xs4all.nl/projects/xda/tools.html. AND, yes, what does GetLastError() return after the call of CeMountDBVolEx() returns FALSE?

Comment: store.vol is a file in Windows Phone7. Sms message stored at store.vol. Now i want to read sms from store.vol.